# Laravel аутентификация

Tags: laravel

Подскажите какой функцией сгенерировать пароль для аутентификации? А то не могу понять какой алгоритм используется в Ларавел!

Comment: сгенерировать пароль или из пароля сгенерировать хеш для записи в базу?

Comment: Да неправильно выразился,хэш

Answer (score 1):

Есть соответствующий раздел в документации: [**Hashing**](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/hashing)

**Пример:**

```
$password = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(12));
$hash = bcrypt($password);
```